# In jQuery select box change event fires when the element loses focus

Tags: jquery

jQuery [documentation for change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) says:

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

I've tested change() on select boxes in different browsers and it fires when the control looses focus. This makes the user feel nothing is happening when he changes options in the select box.

my solution to this is using click() event instead, but I don't like it since the function is run with every click and the user can't use keyboard to change options.

Is there a way to make change() fire as the documentation says.

Comment: `change` fires when the selected element changes, which just happens to usually be when another loses focus (think about radio buttons - when one loses focus, another one gains focus). `change` events are fired just like the documentation says.

Comment: yes but in select boxes you have only one control and onchange is not fired until you click on other controls which is confusing for most users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
.bind('change click keypress', ...)
```

as this event would be fired more times than selection was changed (there is no ideal solution to that), you have to check if anything was changed from the last time

```
// check if changed
if( $(this).data('selection') != $('option:selected', this).val() ) {
    // if so, update hidden data
    (this).data('selection', $('option:selected', this).val());

    ... your code
}
```

Comment: this way the problem of running the event handler on every click and key press remains.

Comment: you have to handle it yourself - on each event check if selection was changed

Comment: But I still think this should be handled on a lower level and not by me.

Comment: Rather than use keypress you should use keyup to ensure you get all possible changes. For instance using the backspace key will not fire the keypress event. Nicola Peluchetti's answer accomplishes this.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same behaviour you are experiencing only when y changed the values in a select with the keyboard. I solved it like this:

```
$('select').bind('keyup change', function(){
    //put your code here
});
```

You should use keyup so that you are sure tho get the new value inside the function

Answer (score 0):

change event does fire when you select any other option from the dropdown. Can you post your code. Make sure you dont have any js error on the page.

```
$('select').change(function(){
  //On change code goes here.
});
```

Comment: Yes, I use a code like yours and I don't have a script error.

Comment: It fires only when selecting OTHER item, what if user choose the same item again? can we have some trick for that?